# Unexplained performace drop with DATEDIFF function

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a strange issue with a table-valued function in SQL Server (please see code below). When I comment out the `CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(...))` line in the function, then the results are almost instantaneous. When I uncomment it, then it runs somewhat slow (~7 seconds) for the date 2018-02-28 and very slow (more than a minute) for the date 2018-03-31.

`qryLMPDATE` returns a table of one row. What could be causing this issue? One thought is that the `lmpdate` is equal to the `valdate` in 2018-02-28, but in 2018-03-31 the `lmpdate` is different from the `valdate`. Therefore, maybe the query processor is computing the values inefficiently.

To provide further context, `lmpdate` is essentially a constant. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [ife].[qryFoo](@valdate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
     RETURN
         SELECT 
             pol.*,
             CONVERT(INT, (DATEDIFF(day, pol.[RESP_PRIM_DOB], ql.lmpdate) / 365)) AS AttainedAge
         FROM
             (ife.tblFIAResvPol AS pol
         LEFT JOIN 
             ife.qryFeatGLWB(@valdate) AS glwb ON (pol.RESP_CONT = glwb.RESFE_CONT)
                                               AND (pol.ValDate = glwb.ValDate))
         LEFT JOIN 
             ife.qryFeatROP(@valdate) AS qrop ON (pol.RESP_CONT = qrop.RESFE_CONT)
                                              AND (pol.ValDate = qrop.ValDate)
         LEFT JOIN 
             ife.qryLMPDATE(@valdate) AS ql ON pol.ValDate = ql.ValDate
         WHERE
             (((pol.ValDate) = @valdate));

SELECT TOP 2000 * 
FROM ife.qryFoo('2018-02-28');  --takes <1 and 7 seconds, resp.

SELECT TOP 2000 * 
FROM ife.qryFoo('2018-03-31'); --takes <1 and >60 seconds, resp.
```

**EDIT**

Query plan can be found here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bywngenif

This is the code for `ife.qryLMPDATE`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [IFE].[qryLMPDATE](@valdate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
     RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 @valdate AS valdate,
                 marketdate AS lmpdate
    FROM ife.tblfiaoptionvalue
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, MarketDate, @valdate) <= 4
);
```

**LATEST UPDATE**

The culprit was IFE.qryLMPDATE. After modifying the function to use `max()` instead of `top 1`, the performance returned to normal. If someone can find an explanation to this, I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Old code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [IFE].[qryLMPDATE](@valdate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
     RETURN
(
    SELECT TOP 1 @valdate AS valdate,
                 marketdate AS lmpdate
    FROM ife.tblfiaoptionvalue
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, MarketDate, @valdate) <= 4
);
```

New code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [IFE].[qryLMPDATE](@valdate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
     RETURN
(
    SELECT @valdate AS valdate,
           max(marketdate) AS lmpdate
    FROM ife.tblfiaoptionvalue
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, MarketDate, @valdate) <= 4
);
```

Comment: How many rows are returned? Additionally, you are converting it to an INT when the result of DATEDIFF is already an INT, thus is repetitive. Can you [paste the plan?](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). Lastly, I'd flush the plan cache or use  `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`  at the end to ensure that it isn't faster sometimes because it's using one plan versus another. i.e. so you can truly credit the slowness to the `datediff()`

Comment: Also, using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` doesn't [guarantee repetitive results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171442/sort-order-has-been-change-due-to-db-server-movement/171443#171443). Just making sure you didn't care *what 2000* results were returned

Comment: In total about 20,000 rows are returned. I added a link to the plan above.

Comment: Digging into it more, I realized that it's not a direct result of the `CONVERT` or `DATEDIFF`. If I include `lmpdate` it slows down, but if I exclude it, it goes back to normal.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the IFE.qryLMPDATE function only scans IFE.tblFIAOptionValue. But you're right, there isn't an index on that table either. I'll probably try adding an index, and/or storing the `lmpdate` in a table. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the plan, it seems to be because you are getting a table scan on `[ActuarialDW].[IFE].[tblFIAResvFeat]` which i suspect is being queried in the ife.qryLMPDATE function. I suspect you don't have an index on `[ValDate]`. Basically your query is scanning the entire table looking for the value of `[ValDate]='2018-03-31 00:00:00.000'` where it could use an index seek to speed this up. The larger the table, the longer it takes, etc. This is taking up 95% of your query cost... so I'd start here by adding some indexes and retesting.

Comment: Thanks. I added an index and I'm playing around with the code for ife.qryLMPDATE. From my initial results it seems that the "top 1" statement in ife.qryLMPDATE was causing a weird issue. But I'll continue to test tomorrow.

Comment: Was there an order by in that statement? It would hurt it for sure. also are the functions necessary?

Comment: No, there was no order by. Thanks for the help; I found that the root cause involved the `top 1` statement in the ife.qryLMPDATE function. I've updated my question to explain my findings.